# extract a json node from the json

Tags: java, mysql, json

how to extract a json node from another json .for example I want to fetch the "Company Name" i.e "kjh".But using this json parser code I am able to fetch the whole json and not only comapnt name..Can somebody help

```
jsonObject = (JSONObject) new org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser().parse(domainRequest);
final String companyName = (String) jsonObject.get("companyName");
```

here is the Json content:

```
{"companyName":{"Company Name:":"kjh","Address 1:":"kjhhkh","Address 2:":"hkjhkj","Address 3:":"hkjhhkj","Address 4:":"kjhj","Postcode:":898,"Default Email Address:":"kkjkh@y","Company Registration No:":98,"VAT No:":89098,"Website":"http://localhost:9000/#/support/domain/request?formLinkUuid=7f000101-4fdf-160d-814f-dfa60dc80000"}}

{"companyName" : {
     "Company Name:":"kjh",
     "Address 1:":"kjhhkh",
     "Address 2:":"hkjhkj",
     "Address 3:":"hkjhhkj",
     "Address 4:":"kjhj",
     "Postcode:":898,
     "Default Email Address:":"kkjkh@y","Company Registration No:":98,
     "VAT No:":89098,
     "Website":"http://localhost:9000/#/support/domain/request?formLinkUuid=7f000101-4fdf-160d-814f-dfa60dc80000"
 }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed 1 step, you are actually getting a map (key-value pair), using this map get `company name`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        String domainRequest = "{\"companyName\":{\"Company Name:\":\"kjh\",\"Address 1:\":\"kjhhkh\",\"Address 2:\":\"hkjhkj\",\"Address 3:\":\"hkjhhkj\",\"Address 4:\":\"kjhj\",\"Postcode:\":898,\"Default Email Address:\":\"kkjkh@y\",\"Company Registration No:\":98,\"VAT No:\":89098,\"Website\":\"http://localhost:9000/#/support/domain/request?formLinkUuid=7f000101-4fdf-160d-814f-dfa60dc80000\"}}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(domainRequest);
        JSONObject jsonMap = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("companyName"); // Generates HashMap, key-value pair
        String companyName = (String) jsonMap.get("Company Name:"); // from map prepared above get key value
        System.out.println(companyName);
    }
```

**Output**

```
kjh
```

Answer (score 0):

It is weird your json format. You should be check it out.
Remove colon from children property name.

```
       String json =
          "{\"companyName\" : {\n" +
                  "     \"Company Name:\":\"kjh\",\n" +
                  "     \"Address 1:\":\"kjhhkh\",\n" +
                  "     \"Address 2:\":\"hkjhkj\",\n" +
                  "     \"Address 3:\":\"hkjhhkj\",\n" +
                  "     \"Address 4:\":\"kjhj\",\n" +
                  "     \"Postcode:\":898,\n" +
                  "     \"Default Email Address:\":\"kkjkh@y\",\"Company Registration No:\":98,\n" +
                  "     \"VAT No:\":89098,\n" +
                  "     \"Website\":\"http://localhost:9000/#/support/domain/request?formLinkUuid=7f000101-4fdf-160d-814f-dfa60dc80000\"\n" +
                  " }}";

    JsonElement jsonElement = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonElement.class);
    String companyName = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("companyName").getAsJsonObject().get("Company Name:").getAsString();
    System.out.println(companyName);
```